# Help in understanding the solution to AMM 6091

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This a problem from AMM (issue 83) 1976. Here's the problem statement

[image]

The solution to this was published in AMM (issue 85) 1978. I have trouble understanding the part:

> we use $n=N(m,R)= \sum_{j=1}^{m} jf(j)$. At the $j$ th stage we combine $f(j)$ free unimodular parameters $\lambda_k(j)$ with the $j$ th roots of unity to obtain $jf(j)$ unimodular variables.

I am not familiar with words such as 'unimodular' or the process being used here. I would really appreciate any kind of explanation, suggestion, help.

Thank you

Comment: I see, thank you @Gonçalo but still I have no idea of what is being done in the solution.